# Convert PSD Layout to HTML-CSS which responsive and fit all monitor screen sizes

Tags: html, css, web, psd

I'm a graphic designer, I have a small question, Ive learnt some of css and completed the HTML tutorial package over the internet multi time, so I have a good base of html-css coding *at least*, I do want to start converting PSD webdesigns into HTML-CSS, I've seen many tutorials step by step guides etc.. and they were helpful for sure but I'm afraid of many points:

1. The flexible point of the website, which means the following: my monitor is currently 1920x1080, let's say that I will code the website to fit on my screen and someone with a small / big screen than mine would open the site, will he see the objects moved from its original place? because defining by px is measured to fit to the user's monitor as far as I know.
2. Ensuring that the site will be working on at least 3 browsers plus, I know that every browser has its own css base reader and its very hard to set the website to fit all browsers especially internet explorer.

So, I don't want a special help to be honest, all I need is some points / well-guided tutorials to follow to ensure that the points I've reviewed being at least 50% solved..

Comment: This might help you http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/

Comment: You can use bootstrap to take care for your responsive point.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is Responsive Web Design. Literally just search it up on the internet and you'll find tons of resources and blogs.

My tips are:

- For testing multiple browsers download all of them (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE) and when you save your work (do this all the time) open it in all browsers so you know where your errors are coming from
- Use the developer tools on your browsers. Chrome and Firefox have very good developer tools and help me figure our my problems. You can also use it to emulate mobile browsers and show your media queries (explained later).
- Use em instead of px. pixels may look nice on your screen, but if the users screen is small they may find it hard to read your text. here is a good px to em converter http://pxtoem.com/
- Use percentages. For example you can make your content div have width of 80% so that you have some space on both sides of your screen (like the design of stackoverflow). This means that your content will fit on most desktops well. Another example is a navbar, you can make it 100% wide so that it always fits the screen no matter the desktop.
- Then we have media queries. These allows us to change the content based on the size of the screen. For example you can hide the navbar using a media query when a  mobile user is viewing your website. Here is onc elink about media queries:http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html
- Some people still develop for IE8  but it is a pain in the ass. You need to decide whether your audience will be using IE8. I'm guessing as a graphics designer you're going to be making a graphics blog, meaning that your audience will probably be using up to date browsers. So have a think if you really  need to develop for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first point: there are some ready css frameworks, with responsive elements included. The most popular, I suppose, is Twitter Bootstrap. It has [a grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to help you make your html blocks change their width and even [get hidden](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) depending on the viewport width.

If you want to understand the techniques, you can study how **media queries** work.

As about cross browser stuff: you will have to test your pages in all browsers you want to support. That's the rule. On your way, [this link](http://caniuse.com/#search=scroll) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> The flexible point of the website, which means the following: my
>   monitor is currently 1920x1080, let's say that I will code the website
>   to fit on my screen and someone with a small / big screen than mine
>   would open the site, will he see the objects moved from its original
>   place?

The general way to get around this is to build a centered window, thus:

```
<html>
  <div id="container">
     <!-- your design lives here -->
  </div>
</html>

#container
{
  width:728px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

Your design is now set at 728px which should fit most resolutions. You can have graphics that expand beyond this, see the bar at the top of SO, but your content should live inside this container.

Another potential solution to this is to allow you design to be completely flexible and contain all your elements in divs that float about, see [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for an example of a tool that helps with this.

---

> Ensuring that the site will be working on at least 3 browsers plus, I
>   know that every browser has its own css base reader and its very hard
>   to set the website to fit all browsers especially internet explorer.

This is a bain of every web designers life. There is no substitute for good testing here. Something that will help is a CSS rest script like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This will remove **some** of the inconsistencies across browsers. But really you just need to, test and test again.